# SELECT query returns null though the object exist Kotlin\Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

I trying to build alarm clock app using Rooms. My method `repository.getAlarmById(1)` returns **null**. But `repository.getAlarms()`outputs

> Alarm(id=1, min=12, hour=12, enabled=true, isRepeating=true)
>
> Alarm(id=2, min=13, hour=13, enabled=true, isRepeating=true)

Here is **AlarmDao**

```
@Dao
interface AlarmDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM alarm_table")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Alarm>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM alarm_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun getById(id: Int): LiveData<Alarm>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(alarm: Alarm)

    @Delete
    fun delete(alarm: Alarm)
}
```

**AlarmRepository**

```
class AlarmRepository (private val alarmDao: AlarmDao): AlarmDataSource {

    override fun getAlarms(): LiveData<List<Alarm>> {
        return alarmDao.getAll()
    }

    override fun getAlarm(id: Int): LiveData<Alarm> {
        return alarmDao.getById(id)
    }

    override fun saveAlarm(alarm: Alarm) {
        doAsync { alarmDao.insert(alarm) }
    }

    override fun deleteAlarm(alarm: Alarm) {
        doAsync { alarmDao.delete(alarm) }
    }
}
```

And **Alarm** class

```
@Entity(tableName = "alarm_table")
data class Alarm(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Int = 0,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "min")
        var min: Int = -1,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "hour")
        var hour: Int = -1,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "enabled")
        var enabled: Boolean = true,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "isRepeating")
        var isRepeating: Boolean = false )
```

Why do I always get null?

Comment: Put your repository class too

Comment: added repo class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok. My suggestion is 2 things to check.

First. Add `LIMITED 1`  to your query and check it

Second. If not works still, be sure that your `LiveData` works well. Remember that live data just work when an object is changed! May be there is a problem with this issue and you may append observer to your `viewmodel` manually. To test tis problem just simply remove `LiveData` from your return type and check it again.

Comment: You're right. I just removed `LiveData` and get error `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` Than i changed my `getAlarm(id)` method to work via `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and all works! Thanks!
P.S. I'd give you +1 if I could (need 8 more reputation to do that).